# How to toggle text in an element using a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user clicks on my `span` element with the text "show more". I want the text inside the element to change to "Show Less".

```
$("div.fluid.examples span.fluid").click(function(e) {
    this = $(this);
    d = $(this).prevAll("div.fluid.examples p.hiddenp").length;
    if (d>0) {
        this.text("Show Less")
    } else if (d<0) {
        this.text("Show More")
    }
    $(this).prevAll(".hiddenp").fadeToggle(600);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdavadi/nUrSs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do it the regular way, by toggling both the text and the elements on the same click ?

```
$("div.fluid.examples span.fluid").click(function() {
    $(this).text(function(_,txt) {
        return txt == 'Show Less' ? 'Show More' : 'Show Less';
    });
    $(this).prevAll(".hiddenp").fadeToggle(600);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nUrSs/4/)

Comment: Could this not have been written `$(this).text($(this).text()=="Show Less"?"Show More":"Show Less")` instead of the function?

Comment: @mplungjan - yes it could, but if it should is a matter of opinion I guess.

Comment: I see I was not the only one thinking that :) - I guess yours is marginally more readable, but I have not seen the "ignore the index" placeholder before

Comment: @mplungjan - it's not uncommon, some people use `i` or a variable name for the index, but an underscore is valid as well, and it's not used anyway, so why not. I notice the underscore version on SO all the time (I think undefined is responsible for that one ?).

Comment: Its was hard picking what answer to accept but your answer wins out thanks.

Comment: I can see _ used if the index is not needed. I would VASTLY prefer the i if the index IS needed since I automatically associate i with a loop or collection counter

Answer (score 1):

[**Here's a working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/nUrSs/7/)

You should be checking the amount which are `visible`:

```
d = $(this).prevAll("div.fluid.examples p.hiddenp:visible").length;
```

(You just needed to add was the `:visible` bit)

Then, in your if:

```
if (d === 0) { // They're hidden      
   thhis.text("Show Less");
}
else if (d > 0) { // They're not hidden       
   thhis.text("Show More");
}
```

Or, instead of the if, you could use:

```
thhis.text (d === 0 ? "Show Less" : "Show More");
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/nUrSs/8/)

Comment: I fixed a few things in your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nUrSs/6/).

Comment: @CaryHartline Cheers, was a bit of a rushed effort.

Comment: I like your answer as well, if I can accept 2 answers I will surely accept yours as well thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $("div.fluid.examples span.fluid").click(function (e) {
     thhis = $(this);

     d = $(this).prevAll("div.fluid.examples p.hiddenp").length;
     var $text = thhis.text();
     if (d > 0) {
         $text.indexOf('Show Less') > -1 ? thhis.text("Show More") 
                                         : thhis.text("Show Less");
     } else if (d < 0) {
         thhis.text("Show More")
     }
     $(this).prevAll(".hiddenp").fadeToggle(600);

 });
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/nUrSs/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("div.fluid.examples span.fluid").click(function(e) {
     if($(this).text() == "Show More"){
        $(this).text("Show Less");
     }else{
        $(this).text("Show More");
     }

     $(this).prevAll(".hiddenp").fadeToggle(600);

});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/nUrSs/5/

You could also tighten up the code with a ternary operator:

```
 $("div.fluid.examples span.fluid").click(function(e) {
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.text($this.text() == "Show More" ? "Show Less":"Show More");

     $(this).prevAll(".hiddenp").fadeToggle(600);
});
```